# How to display a dialog box with warning message in Wix installer?

Tags: wix

I need to display a warning message while running my installer if a firefox maintenance service is installed. 
To achieve this, I added a registry search property, and then added the code for dialog box in wix:

```
    <Property Id="MAINTENANCESERVICEINSTALLED">
  <RegistrySearch Id="MSID" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Mozilla\MaintenanceService" Name="Installed" Type="raw"/>
</Property>
    <UI>
  <Dialog Id="MaintenanceServiceWarningDialog" Width="284" Height="73" Title="Warning" NoMinimize="yes">
    <Control Id="Text" Type="Text" X="38" Y="8" Width="240" Height="40" TabSkip="no">
      <Text>Firefox Maintenance is installed on your system. Disable it to prevent compatibility issues. Click OK to proceed.</Text>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="OK" Type="PushButton" X="114" Y="52" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes"  Cancel="yes" Text="OK">
      <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
    </Control>
  </Dialog>  
<InstallUISequence>
  <Show Dialog="MaintenanceServiceWarningDialog" Sequence="1"> <![CDATA[NOT Installed AND MAINTENANCESERVICEINSTALLED]]></Show>
</InstallUISequence>
</UI>
```

I am using  to show the dialog box. The above code is under "Product" tag. 
I am getting build issues with this like below. And when I move the UI code to Fragment, the installer does not display anything. Not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your `InstallUISequence` element is inside the `UI` element.